# How to display a picture on webserver when pythonscript saves it to files?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, server, web-development-server

I'm trying to develop a server on a PC for running measurments remotely. I decided to try doing it in react which has proven much harder for me to grasp than I initially thought it would be.

I have one server file(server.js), one App.js component and the html file. In the server.js I am starting python scripts that do measurements. The python script saves a plot to file(img) every few seconds and I would like to display it on the web page whenever there is an updated picture.

I currently use Python Shell to run the script, it works great for sending arguments to the script and I can also display some feedback using the `res.send(args)`. The issue is that I cannot use the `renderDOM` function in the sever file, and that is how I render all of the other things on the page that I have created in the App.js file.

I tried to make a component Showresults.js which used ´RenderDOM´ to render the image, but this obviously only rendered once because I cant call it from the server.js. Its very frustrating not to understand how to trigger the rendering without like a buttonclick.

App.js file structure

```
class App extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
super(props);
 this.state = {
     mystate: ""
 }
}
 this.handle_state = this.handle_state.bind(this);

 handle_state(event){
 this.setState{( mystate = event.target.value )}


render(){
return(
    <div>
      <button onclick={handle_state}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  });
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Server.js file structure

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/myscriptpath', function (req, res) {
   var pythonProcess = Pythonshell.run('myscript.py', args);

    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    res.send(data);
});


   });
```

So the `res.send` displays the prints from the python scripts, but how do I actually update the page with a new picture from a file several times? If I cant make a component that renders a picture and call it in the server.js? I will be extremely happy for any response.